# Login into Instagram using python

Tags: python, api

I want to make a python script to login in to python without instagram library.

I just use this script and it isn't working...

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://instagram.com', auth=('user', 'pass'))

print r.status_code
print r.headers['content-type']
```

Can you help me please...

Comment: Please study the Requests library properly. You need to make a post request rather than a get request with all the required post data. Before doing that you will also need to create a Requests session and maintain that for cookies. Hope that helps.

Comment: why not use python with instagram library? Do you mean do not use this: https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram?

Comment: Problem is that i do not want to use this library

Comment: I am trying to make instagram bruteforce script so thats why i am asking you for not to use instagram library

Answer (score -1):

Just use selenium.

```
 from selenium import webdriver

 driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('path to phantomjs executable')
 driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login')
 dom = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*')
 username = dom.find_element_by_name('username')
 password = dom.find_element_by_name('password')
 login_button = dom.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="_aj7mu _taytv _ki5uo _o0442"]')
 username.clear()
 password.clear()
 username.send_keys('your username')
 password.send_keys('your password')
 login_button.click()
 driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login')
 if 'logged-in' in driver.page_source:
  print 'Logged in'
```

Make sure you grab a copy of phantomjs here http://www.phantomjs.org